# Extended functionality for <input> tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to create a component that contains an `<input>` tag and adds extra functionality to it, such as a clear text value "X" icon, or any other custom actions and markup, whilst preserving the same event bindings (`(click)`, `(keyup)`, etc) of the native input element.
Example:

```
<my-input (keyup)="handleKeystroke($event)" (click)="handleClick($event)" [customProp]="...">
```

Is it possible to do this without explicitly creating custom outputs and event handlers on the child input element internally for ALL possible event bindings?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, using ControlValueAccessor  interface

Here is sample code you need to add when you implements in your component class

```
const TYPE_CONTROL_ACCESSOR = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => YourComponent ),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-control',
  templateUrl: './custom-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-control.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [TYPE_CONTROL_ACCESSOR]
})

 export class YourComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

 private onTouch: Function;
 private onModelChange: Function;

 writeValue(obj: string): void {
      this.value = obj;
 }
 registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
      this.onModelChange = fn;
 }
 registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
 this.onTouch = fn;
 }
```

You can bind event from your template ( HTML ) and capture them in your component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it looks like it's what I need. Once I do a basic implementation I'll confirm the solution.

Comment: This solution is only partial. It allows my component to work as a formControl but I don't see how it can map all DOM-level event bindings from the input element to the host element. E.g. (click), (mousemove), (drag), and many others

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using ControlValueAccessor.
Take a look at the documentation https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor.
And try googling for examples.

Answer (score -1):

You have a very nice example of custom event here:
[Angular event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: I didn't ask what an EventEmitter is or how to use it.